# Cannot install libv8 gem on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I am having problems installing the Ruby libv8 gem on OS X Mavericks(10.9.4), I get the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.11.8.13/ext/libv8/compiler.rb:30: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
../src/cached-powers.cc:136:18: error: unused variable 'kCachedPowersLength' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kCachedPowersLength = ARRAY_SIZE(kCachedPowers);
```

I tried to tell clang not to error out when there is an unused constant using the following, but to no avail the result was the same:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-const-variable gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'
```

What command line option am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on my machine. Using the `--with-system-v8` flag resolved the problem. Full documentation on this flag [here](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8#bring-your-own-v8).